# Preventing an event before other callback finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have an application that uses backbone.js and jQuery for UI. I have a form on a page, attached to the form's text box blur event is a function that under certain conditions shows the user a popup and awaits it's input - the conditions are checked using an ajax call to a WCF service.

Everything works fine until i click the form's submit button while the focus is set on the text field - then the popup is displayed but behind it the form is submitted.

Of course the proper result would be cancelling the second event(if the popup is displayed the form definitely cannot be submitted)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i can'T understand you but probably this is what you need: event.stopPropagation();

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Or .off()

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: isn't event.stopPropagation meant for stoping that exact event from bubbling up the DOM tree. My problem is that I have two separate events fired - blur and submit button pressed. But I would like to cancel the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the clicking of 'submit' is causing the popup to display - and this is not one of the 'certain conditions' where it should be displayed? I would consider adding a condition to the blur handler that checks to see if the submit button was clicked. Dont display the popup in this case.

Cancel the event in the onSubmit handler -

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
evt.cancel()
//dont want to catch it again
form.removeEventListener(this)   
popup.show()
//have the popup call submit when done, it wont be caught again
}
```

Comment: The popup has to be displayed but the submit should not go through

Comment: 'You can also return false from the handler instead of calling preventDefault(), but this will also stop the propagation of the submit event to ancestor elements, which you may not want.' 

This solution will ensure the propagation  will be the same as the normal submit event -

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the `<form>` and call its [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) method to inhibit submission if the popup is visible:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if ($("selector_matching_your_popup").is(":visible")) {
        e.preventDefault();  // Cancel submission.
    }
});
```

You can also return `false` from the handler instead of calling `preventDefault()`, but this will also stop the propagation of the `submit` event to ancestor elements, which you may not want.